# Do we need any database.yml file for Ruby on rails application using Redis

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, redis

I have created a Ruby on Rails application without active records:-

```
$ rails new rails_using_redis_demo_app --skip-active-record
```

Now in order to perform database operation to i have to include database.yml file containing the necessary details regarding the database adapter.

I have also include follwing in my gemfile:-

```
gem 'redis'
```

I also found that redis actually stores the data in a .rdb file with key value pair, which can be accessed with the help of keys present. Am I doing things in a right manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you removed all occurences to ActiveRecord in your Rails config files ?

Perhaps you should check your application.rb file.

A typical application.rb file includes

```
require 'rails/all'
```

That is what you should write instead to fully remove ActiveRecord

```
# Pick the frameworks you want:
# require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: Do we need to have any .yml file for database configuration in our config directory for redis.

Comment: I don't think so. An initializer should do the trick, as explained in this tutorial : http://jimneath.org/2011/03/24/using-redis-with-ruby-on-rails.html